Fuzzy spheres in the large-N limit
My question concerns fuzzy sphere solutions and how they fit into the large-$N$ limit of gauge theory.
The Berenstein-Maldacena-Natasse (BMN) model is a matrix model that arises in string theory. The action (restricted to the bosonic variables only, as the fermions will be irrelevant for what follows) is:
$$ S_b = \frac{N}{\lambda} \int \mathrm{d} t \, \text{Tr} \Bigg[\frac{1}{2} D_{t} X^i D_{t} X^i + \frac{1}{4} [X^i, X^j]^2 - \frac{i\mu}{3} \epsilon^{rst} X^r X^s X^t - \frac{\mu^2}{18} (X^r)^2 - \frac{\mu^2}{72} (X^m)^2 \Bigg] \,. $$
Here, $X^i$ for $i=1, ..., 9$ are $N \times N$ bosonic matrices, $D_t$ is the gauge covariant derivative, $\mu$ is a mass deformation parameter, and the indices $r,s,t \in \{1,2,3\}$ whereas $m = 4, ..., 9$. The reason for splitting the indices into two disjoint groups is that the mass deformation has broken the $SO(9)$ symmetry of the BFSS model (recovered by setting $\mu=0$) down to $SO(3) \times SO(6)$. The prefactor term $1/g^2_{YM} = N/\lambda$ is the inverse gauge coupling squared.
The theory admits a large-$N$ 't Hooft limit in which $N \rightarrow \infty$ while $\lambda$ is kept constant. General scaling arguments imply that in this limit the action should scale as $S_b \sim N^2$. For example, the Euclidean action can be identified with the free energy, which scales as $N^2$ in the deconfined phase. This suggests that general single-trace operators scale linearly, independent of their degree:
$$ \langle \text{Tr} (X ... X) \rangle \sim N . $$
Fuzzy spheres are non-commuting classical solutions where $X^m = 0$ for $m=4,...,9$ and where dimensions 1, 2, 3 matrices satisfy
$$ [X^r, X^s] = i\, \mu \, \epsilon^{rst} \, X^t \,.$$
The above equation is solved by setting $X^r = \mu \, J^r$, where $J^r$ is a $N$-dimensional representation of the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$. Using the fact that the Casimir operator for $SU(2)$ representations satisfies $(J^r)^2 = \frac{N^2-1}{4} \, 1_{N \times N}$,
$$ \langle \text{Tr} ( X^r X^r ) \rangle = \frac{N(N^2-1)\mu^2}{4} \,, $$
which clearly does not scale in the expected way. It so happens that this solution is supersymmetric, and so the energy (and action) vanishes, and so there is no direct contradiction due to the energy scaling improperly. However, semiclassical corrections lift the energy in the bosonic-only theory where the fermions are neglected, in which case the energy scales like $E \sim N^4$. (See, e.g., Eq. 1.1 and 4.8 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08781 - though note that they have omitted the $N$ prefactor in their definition of the Hamiltonian, and therefore find that $E \sim N^3$ in their conventions).
My question is: do the fuzzy sphere solutions/states survive the large-$N$ limit? The answer may depend on whether theory is supersymmetric (in which case the energy is protected from corrections). In the non-supersymmetric case, it seems like the fuzzy sphere states will have infinite energy and will therefore not survive the large-$N$ limit.
